# Getting user password from ArcSDE using Workspace Properties - python

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase, python-script-tool, connection, password

Looking at this page for getting [Workspace Properties](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/workspace-properties.htm) I am wondering if there is a simple way to get a Users password from an existing SDE connection on the users machine?

Using the code sample from the aforementioned link, something like this:

```
desc = arcpy.Describe(r"C:data\Connection to state.sde")
cp = desc.connectionProperties
print("%-12s %s" % ("  Password:", cp.password))
```

---

For clarification this is for a custom Python Script Tool that creates a new SDE connection as part of the code.  Currently I have the user enter their user name and pword in the tool prompt.  If I could however have them simply select an existing database connection on their machine and use the creds from that it would be much simpler and less error prone.

I do not think this presents a security risk because it would only have local application.  A user would be accessing their own info to automate a process on their personal machine.

There are both Oracle and SQL Servers,  I will put logic into the tool that will differentiate between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, the password is stored encrypted in the connection file and is not exposed as a connection property.

The only properties you can query are listed in the [documentation](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/workspace-properties.htm) you linked to.

What you could do is either have them input credentials and create a new connection *or* just reuse the existing connection.

Comment: That was my assumption but I thought I would put it out there.  Thanks.